# Chrome Extension background.js throws Uncaught EvalError as soon as I import anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, service-worker

I'm trying to make a chrome extension, and everything works fine, but as soon as I try to import any module the service worker becomes inactive and I get the following error:
[image: Uncaught EvalError]

manifest.json

```
{
    "name":"Site Analyzer",
    "description":"Analyze the text content of the site.",
    "version":"0.1.0",
    "manifest_version":3,
    "action":{
        "default_popup":"popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        popup:"./src/popup.jsx",
        background: "./src/background.js"
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        clean:true
    },
    module:{
        rules:[{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins:[
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template:"./src/popup.html",
            filename: "popup.html"
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns:[{from:"public"}]
        })
    ]

}
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "arquero": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
import * as aq from "arquero";

const table1 = aq.table({a:["whatewer","there"],b:["beep","boop"]});
console.log(table1.objects());
```

The file that gets built even works "node ./dist/background.js"

When I searched regarding the error, most issues were regarding '--mode development' and not present in production mode.
I attempted the different 'devtool' options in webpack config but there wasn't any difference.
When I made an .env file with "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false;", there wasn't any change.

ps.: Yes, I rebuilt, cleaned the errors in the extension, and even refreshed it between attempts. :/

Comment: 1) Use `devtool: "inline-source-map"` in your webpack config. 2) The modules you import probably use `eval` or `new Function`.